# How to listen to keyboard events in Jetpack Compose WITHOUT a TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a text input where I can NOT use `TextField`. I need text transformations that are not supported by `TextField`.

How can I get software/onscreen keyboard events?

`Modifier.onKeyEvent()` does not work for me as for some reason it only works for hardware keyboard.

This should be easy, right? I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Not sure do this workaround create a textfield with small size and get it focused and get events and modify your other things based on events

Comment: I have been thinking about something like that: a hidden textfield, elevation -10, etc. But it is a hack, there should be a simple and correct way imo.

Comment: You don't have a hardware keyboard, you don't want to show a soft keyboard yet you want to listen to keyboard events, so the question is, how will the user type in a key to generate the event you want to listen?

Comment: to clarify: I want to use the software keyboard. As stated in the question: "How can I get software/onscreen keyboard events?"

Answer (score 5):

I found a way... Maybe not the most elegant, but it worked...

First, in your activity, capture the key event and send it via [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

```kotlin
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
        Intent("key_up").apply {
            putExtra("event", event)
        }
    )
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
}
```

Then declare the function below (wherever you want). It is responsible to open the keyboard.

```kotlin
suspend fun openKeyboard(context: Context) {
    val myView = (context as Activity).findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    val inputMethodManager = 
        context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    delay(500) // it didn't work without the delay...
    inputMethodManager?.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
        myView.applicationWindowToken,
        InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
        0
    )
}
```

Finally, here it is the composable.

```kotlin
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun FakeInput() {
    var keyCode by remember { // last key pressed
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        openKeyboard(ctx)
    }
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx)
        // Receiver for key events 
        val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(ctx: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                intent?.getParcelableExtra<KeyEvent>("event")?.let { keyEvent ->
                    keyCode = keyEvent.displayLabel.toString()
                }
            }
        }
        // registering the receiver
        lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("key_up"))
        onDispose {
            // unregistering when the composable is disposed
            lbm.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = keyCode, Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanx nglauber: Best solution for now. I guess we will have to wait till a compose-native solution is available.

Comment: Is possible to change keyboard input to numeric keyboard?

Comment: Thank god Compose is here to rescue us from the complexity of the view framework.